# SQlite Timestamp difference in Python and C

Tags: python, c, sqlite

I am having a problem as I attempt to migrate a program from Python to C. In Python I was able to store a "Timestamp" and in C I had to use TEXT to get it to work. But now when I search  between a given date, it just loops endlessly. I think it is an issue with the Timestamp vs Text? The database looks correct other than that?

Both searches look like:

```
SELECT timestamp, df1 FROM PLCValues where timestamp BETWEEN '2019-02-25 18:42:50' AND '2019-03-04 18:42:50'
```

Python I write the create a table with

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLCValues(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [timestamp] timestamp, \
    x001 NUMERIC, x002 NUMERIC, x003 NUMERIC, x004 NUMERIC, x005 NUMERIC, x006 NUMERIC, x007 NUMERIC, x008 NUMERIC,\
    y001 NUMERIC, y002 NUMERIC, y003 NUMERIC, y004 NUMERIC, y005 NUMERIC, y006 NUMERIC,\
    x201 NUMERIC, x202 NUMERIC, x203 NUMERIC, x204 NUMERIC, x205 NUMERIC, x206 NUMERIC, x207 NUMERIC, x208 NUMERIC,\
    df1 REAL, df2  REAL, df3 REAL, df4 REAL)")
```

and populate the table with

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO PLCValues VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",\
            (datetime.now(), \
            regs1[0], regs1[1], regs1[2], regs1[3], regs1[4], regs1[5], regs1[6], regs1[7],\
            regs2[0], regs2[1], regs2[2], regs2[3], regs2[4], regs2[5],\
            regs3[0], regs3[1], regs3[2], regs3[3], regs3[4], regs3[5], regs3[6], regs3[7],\
            Temp/10, Humid/10, 0, 0))
```

In C I had todo things a little different.

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLCValues(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, timestamp TEXT, \
    x001 NUMERIC, x002 NUMERIC, x003 NUMERIC, x004 NUMERIC, x005 NUMERIC, x006 NUMERIC, x007 NUMERIC, x008 NUMERIC,\
    y001 NUMERIC, y002 NUMERIC, y003 NUMERIC, y004 NUMERIC, y005 NUMERIC, y006 NUMERIC,\
    x201 NUMERIC, x202 NUMERIC, x203 NUMERIC, x204 NUMERIC, x205 NUMERIC, x206 NUMERIC, x207 NUMERIC, x208 NUMERIC,\
    df1 REAL, df2  REAL, df3 REAL, df4 REAL)";
```

And then populate the table with

```
strftime(TimeStamp, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));
printf("%s\n",TimeStamp);

char *sql = "INSERT INTO PLCValues VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);

if (rc == SQLITE_OK ) {

  //Bind the variables  
    sqlite3_bind_text(res, 1, TimeStamp, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have fixed the issue.

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLCValues(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, \
    x001 NUMERIC, x002 NUMERIC, x003 NUMERIC, x004 NUMERIC, x005 NUMERIC, x006 NUMERIC, x007 NUMERIC, x008 NUMERIC,\
    y001 NUMERIC, y002 NUMERIC, y003 NUMERIC, y004 NUMERIC, y005 NUMERIC, y006 NUMERIC,\
    x201 NUMERIC, x202 NUMERIC, x203 NUMERIC, x204 NUMERIC, x205 NUMERIC, x206 NUMERIC, x207 NUMERIC, x208 NUMERIC,\
    df1 REAL, df2  REAL, df3 REAL, df4 REAL)";
```

Comment: ya, this is a SQL issue, not a Python or C issue.